# Flutter Container with BeveledRectangleBorder border

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a view something like this.

[image: Required Output]

But the issue is that while using [BeveledRectangleBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BeveledRectangleBorder-class.html), the border width of that side is not matching the whole border width.

[image: Current output]

I am using the below code:-

```html
Material(
      color: Colors.black,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .10),
          width: 2,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(
            ScreenUtil().setHeight(15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: new Container(
        width: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .10),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
            topRight: Radius.circular(5),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
          ),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .10),
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
        child: new Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: In addition to the answer mentioned below, you could make the line a little thicker and the effect will be less noticeable.

Comment: After years, how did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Example]

Not sure on how to explain this but in my example the two lines are the same length. It looks like the rendering is taking the width from `BorderSide` and not using that perpendicular to the beveled edge but just as a horizontal width.

I'm not sure on how to fix this and if this is working as intended or a bug.
You might want to post this as an issue on the flutter github.

```dart
Material(
        color: Colors.black,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1),
            width: 30,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(
              80,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: new Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      )
```